# When would you vs when you would in a sentence

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

Which is correct:

1. Please let me know when WILL YOU go.
2. Please let me know when YOU WILL go.

Also:

1. I don't know when would he arrive.
2. I don't know when he would arrive.

Please explain why. Thanks! :)

Comment: *when WILL YOU go* is a ***question***. The syntax of preceding *Please let me know* expects to be followed by ***something*** (the thing you want to know, some kind of "noun"). And *when YOU WILL go* IS a ***noun phrase***. Even native speakers (especially, relaxed or indifferently-educated ones) make this "error", but it's particularly something that non-native speakers are prone to (probably, those who speak specific languages with specific "question grammar" features).

Answer (score 1):

"Order of words in an interrogative sentence is as follows:

Verb + subject + ............................?

When will ( Verb ) you ( subject ) come ?..-"

https://www.quora.com/Which-sentence-is-correct-When-will-you-come-or-When-you-will-come

However, If you said it either way, any English speaker would understand you and it would be correct.

Edit: The second one of both personally sounds better to me, however I believe above is the correct way to structure it.

Answer (score 0):

**Direct questions**

A feature of direct questions in English is that the subject and verb are inverted.  So statements such as "I am" and "I will go" become "Am I?" and "Will I go?".  If there is no auxiliary verb in the statement, a dummy verb "do" must be added to the statement prior to inversion: "I go" --> "I do go" --> "Do I go?".

Interrogatives added to the start retain this inverted order: "Who am I?", "When will I go?".  The exception is if where the interrogative is a subject pronoun.  So, whereas we say "Who(m) did I kiss?" (because "who(m)" is an object pronoun), we say "Who kissed me?" (because "who" is a subject pronoun directly replacing the name of the person who performed the action).

As a direct question, we say "When will you go?" and "When would he arrive?".

Occasionally, we express a question simply through a rising intonation, without changing the word order.  So "I am?" and "He went there?" can be questions.  The non-inverted form of "When will you go?", however, wouldn't be "When you will go?".  Rather, it would be "You will go when?".  Similarly, "He would arrive when?".

**Indirect questions**

As indirect questions embedded in subordinate clauses, there is **no inversion** of subject and verb.  So "I don't know when you will go"; "I asked when he would arrive"; "Please let me know when you will go".

> Please let me know when WILL YOU go.

Wrong - because you have inverted the subject and verb, which is invalid here for the reasons explained above.  This could only work as two separate sentences: "Please let me know - when will you go?".

> Please let me know when YOU WILL go.

Correct.

> I don't know when would he arrive.

Wrong - the subject and verb in the subordinate clause have been inverted, which they shouldn't be here.  It could only work as two sentences: "I don't know.  When would he arrive?".

> I don't know when he would arrive.

Correct.